# If clause in Z3py without the else

Tags: python, z3, z3py

How do we write an If('condition', x, y) clause in Z3py if we don't have the 'else' part ?

Comment: @TDG Gives me an error in Z3py if I omit the else part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All expressions in z3 produce a value; think of it like a functional programming language as opposed to an imperative one. So, you *have* to provide the `else` clause.

This sort of thing usually comes up when modeling imperative languages in z3; something like:

```py
foo = expr1
if cond:
   foo = expr2
```

The proper way to model this is to use the so called [SSA form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form), and "keep" the old value, i.e., the above becomes:

```
foo0 = expr1
foo1 = If(cond, expr2, foo0)
```

Note that each assignment to the "same" variable gets a new name (`foo0`, `foo1`, etc.), and when a value doesn't change through a conditional, we just keep its old value. Most of the symbolic-simulation systems (like [Klee](https://klee.github.io), or other higher-level APIs) do this under the hood for you. Note that coming up with the correct assignment, while it can be automated, can be tricky, depending on the type of `foo`. (What if it's a list?)

To address your programming needs, it's always best to ask specific instances where you needed this construct; otherwise the answers will necessarily be generalizations. That is, while the above is the general strategy, your particular problem might have an easier solution. But it's impossible to know without further details of exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Z3 expressions are first-order logic formulas, not statements. If `x` and `y` are booleans, `If(b,x,y)` is equivalent to `b && x || !b && y`. Omitting `y` is equivalent to replacing it with `true`, and also to `b ==> x`, i.e. `Implies(b, x)` in Z3py.

Thinks are more complicated if `x` and `y` are not booleans, but, e.g. integers. In this case, the conditional is essentially the ternary operator `b ? x : y`. Since functions (and thus operators) are total in SMT, you cannot simply omit `y` (what would `b ? x` evaluate to if `b` were false?).

In this situation, you can work with an underspecified variable: Declare a fresh SMT variable `z` and constraint it by `Implies(b, z == x)`. This way, `z` is known to be `x` if `b` is true, and if `b` is false, `z` has some unknown value.